# symbols in paths in React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm migrating from v5 to v6. It v6 [it seems](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/v5.md) you can't use regexp anymore. Is there a quick workaround for a path like this? The problem is the dash, of course.

```
<Route path="/doc/:id-:version" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use partial dynamic segments, it's all or nothing. Use a single param and then apply string splitting logic on it in the component.

Example:

```
<Route path="/doc/:idVersion" element={....} />
```

```js
const { idVersion } = useParams();

const [id, version] = idVersion.split("-");
```

See [Dynamic Segments](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#dynamic-segments) for more information.

Comment: I know that, I wanted to avoid moving the logic in the component. It seems there is no way at the moment. I'm not even sure I agree/understand their explanation about this design decision.
`We added the dependency on path-to-regexp in v4 to enable more advanced pattern matching. In v6 we are using a simpler syntax that allows us to predictably parse the path for ranking purposes. It also means we can stop depending on path-to-regexp, which is nice for bundle size.`

Comment: @alfredopacino If you didn't want to push the string processing logic to the component you could write a wrapper component to do that and then pass `id` and `version` as props of some form to the *actual* component, but that's just moving deck chairs. If you have control over the link then separating these into different path segments might be preferred, e.g. `"/doc/:id/:version"`, then RRD does all the work. Yeah, removal of path rexexp was initially a hit, but I've grown to not really miss it. At least they gave us back optional path segments.